# Django does not recognize specific change in model

Tags: django, django-models, django-migrations

```py
class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128 , unique=True)
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    # we override save so as to convert name to a slug
    ### essentially -> name.lower().replace(" " , "-")

    def save(self,*args,**kwargs):
        self.slug = slugify(self.name)
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
```

The save override is not registering. I get a *"No changes detected in app"* message when trying to run `makemigrations`.

I have tried making changes in the other methods, and the changes are recognized.

What could be causing this?

Comment: The `save` overriding does *not* yield any changes at all to the database tables. Hence no changes are necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Migrations make changes to the database. Overriding methods, adding properties, defining new methods, etc. is all located at the Python/Django level, and has *nothing* to do with the database, hence there are *no* migrations necessary for that. How would you change the database with the given new `.save(..)` method?

If you need to populate your existing records, you can construct a [*data migration* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/migrations/#data-migrations). You can construct such a migration with:

```
python manage.py makemigrations --empty appname
```

and then specify how to migrate (for example by manually iterating over your records, and each time calculating the slug).

Note that your `Category` model however has *no* `slug` field either, so that means that `self.slug = …` is not very useful. You will add an attribute `.slug` to your model object. But once that object is no longer in memory, that data is no longer available. Furthermore you can not search on a `slug`, since the slug is not stored in the database.

You might want to take a look at the [**`django-autoslug`** package [readthedocs]](https://django-autoslug.readthedocs.io/en/latest/). This allows you to define an `AutoSlugField`, and just specify how to populate it. Furthermore this package will try to find a *unique* slug, after all a different name could, strictly speaking, result in the same slug.

```
from autoslug import AutoSlugField

class Category(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128 , unique=True)
    slug = AutoSlugField(populate_from='name')
    views = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

    class Meta:
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
```

Comment: A missing field led me to understand what migrations are actually doing. I thought it was a sort of version-control for the `models.py` file until now. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Migrations only are for **database** changes; Your overriding in save method won't have anything to do with database (like adding a new field, etc.), so it won't generate any migrations.